# CakePHP Form Error to add a class

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.5

Is there a way to test if a particular text field has an error so that i can add a Class to highlight the who text box

```
<div class="form-group">
    <?php echo $this->Form->label('name', 'Name:', array('class' => 'col-sm-2 control-label')); ?>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <?php echo $this->Form->text('name', array('required' => false, 'class' => 'form-control input-lg')); ?>
        <?php echo $this->Form->error('name', null, array('class' => 'label label-block label-danger text-left', 'wrap' => 'label')); ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

i want to add `has-error` to `<div class="form-group">` div if `name` has any errors

Comment: You should think about using a CakePHP plugin for Bootstrap to avoid these problem, most of them would automatically add the `has-error` class to the `form-group` div if there is an error in `name`.

Comment: thanks will check it out :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
$this->Form->isFieldError('fieldname');
```

```
<div class="form-group <?= ($this->Form->isFieldError('name'))? 'has-error': '' ; ?>">
    <?php echo $this->Form->label('name', 'Name:', array('class' => 'col-sm-2 control-label')); ?>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <?php echo $this->Form->text('name', array('required' => false, 'class' => 'form-control input-lg')); ?>
        <?php echo $this->Form->error('name', null, array('class' => 'label label-block label-danger text-left', 'wrap' => 'label')); ?>
    </div>
</div>
```